# How to move a colorbar label downward?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm wondering if there's a good way to move a colorbar's label vertically down by some offset?

I've tried *bar.ax.yaxis.labelpad*, which allows me to move the label horizontally by some offset, but not vertically.

I know of *bar.ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(x,y)*, which can explicitly set the coordinates. But the problem is that I don't know how to obtain the initial coordinate values for me to set a relative offset for y coord.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a way, it's either what you have there or add a text box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to change the y-position of the label on a vertical colorbar, change the y-coordinate.  The default value is `0.5`, and the units are fractions of the colorbar's height.

For example, let's place the label 1/4 of the way up the colorbar instead of 1/2:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10, 10)), cmap='gist_earth')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
cbar.set_label('Test', y=0.25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You might also want to place it at the end of the colorbar.  In that case, you'd probably want to change the alignment of the text, as well.  Note that text aligmentment in matplotlib will be relative to the text's pre-rotation position by default (depends on the value of `rotation_mode`).  Therefore, we'll want to change the *horizontal* alignment of the text, rather than its vertical alignment.

For example, let's place the text aligned with the top of the colorbar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10, 10)), cmap='gist_earth')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
cbar.set_label('Test', y=1.0, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And the bottom:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10, 10)), cmap='gist_earth')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
cbar.set_label('Test', y=0, ha='left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Finally, you might also want the text going the other way.  In that case, you'd adjust the rotation and both vertical and horizontal alignment of the text (again, alignment is relative to the pre-rotation text):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10, 10)), cmap='gist_earth')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
cbar.set_label('Test', y=0, ha='right', rotation=-90, va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image]